# Is good practice to inject Transactional service to another transactional service in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm in consternation. I found posts about inject `@Service` class to another `@Service` class. But what if the both classes have `@Transactional` annotation? `@Transactional` makes a difference or maybe better practise is inject repositories?

Simple exmaple:

```
@Transactional
@Service
public class BBBServiceImpl implements BBBService {
    
    private final BBBRepository bbbRepository;

    // @Autowired constructor, methods etc...
    
}
```

second class:

```
@Transactional
@Service
public class AAAServiceImpl implements AAAService {

    private final AAARepository aaaRepository;
    private final BBBService bbbService;
    
    @Autowired
    public AAAServiceImpl(AAARepository aaaRepository, BBBService bbbService) {
        this.aaaRepository = aaaRepository;
        this.bbbService = bbbService;
    }

    // methods etc...
}
```

Or better solution is:

```
@Transactional
@Service
public class AAAServiceImpl implements AAAService {

    private final AAARepository aaaRepository;
    private final BBBRepository bbbRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    public AAAServiceImpl(AAARepository aaaRepository, BBBRepository bbbRepository) {
        this.aaaRepository = aaaRepository;
        this.bbbRepository= bbbRepository;
    }

    // methods etc...

}
```

Comment: If business cases demands that `BBBServiceImpl` must be `@Transactional`, but also demant something in `AAAServiceImpl` needs a trasction to, for example, encapsulate some action with a call to `BBBService` in a transaction, then you have no other choice. In general, the transaction will be resued. You can, however, change this behaviour by setting the Propagation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, *classes* shouldn't be transactional but rather their methods. You should apply `@Transactional` if *the item concerned* needs transactionality. Sometimes this means that you'll compose multiple levels, because you can see that even individually the pieces need `@Transactional`. Sometimes it means that only one level in the stack needs it. You must determine based on the logical requirements of your software.

A case where it makes sense to apply `@Transactional` is where you have a service that coordinates shipment of orders; the updates to mark the order shipped and to write the parcel information should happen transactionally. Therefore, `OrderHandlingService#shipParcel` should be `@Transactional`, and *so should* any methods involving data handling.

Comment: You have right. I should add `@Transactional` only for methods which need it, not on entire class.

Comment: What it That class interacts with repository and for every call in that class it goes to the database?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, Service layer (**Manager**) represents your business logic and hence it should be annotated with `@Transactional`.

Service layer may call different DAOs to perform DB operations. Lets assume a situation where you have 3 DAO operations in a service method. If your 1st DAO operation failed, other two may be still passed and you will end up with an inconsistent DB state. Annotating Service layer can save you from such situations.

Also it's depends on [**`Propagation and Isolation`**](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-transaction-propagation) values as well.

Even though you want to continue with same transaction but on service B it's Propagation is **`Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW`** it will create new transaction and perform business.

Comment: Thanks for useful article. I think the best way for me is rollback everything when 
either method throw an exception. I generete thousands of terms in timetable and check for leaves, conflicts and holidays, so everything have to be fine from A to B, so default `REQUIRED` method should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Since you can call another service inside a service even it is transactional or not. No problem & recommended